# Elasticsearch java client: Jackson's ObjectMapper can only be used with the JacksonJsonpProvider

Tags: java, elasticsearch, quarkus

I use elasticsearch-java client version 7.17 and the server is 7.10.
I wanted to use ElasticsearchClient, but seems server version doesn't support it.

So, I decided to use RestClient and json Object. I map the SearchRequest to Request with the following code:

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
JsonGenerator generator = JacksonJsonProvider.provider().createGenerator(writer);
searchRequest.serialize(generator, new JacksonJsonpMapper());
```

but it throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Jackson's ObjectMapper can only be used with the JacksonJsonpProvider

    at co.elastic.clients.json.jackson.JacksonJsonpMapper.serialize(JacksonJsonpMapper.java:75)
    at co.elastic.clients.json.JsonDataImpl.serialize(JsonDataImpl.java:101)
    at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.query_dsl.RangeQuery.serializeInternal(RangeQuery.java:187)
    at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.query_dsl.QueryBase.serialize(QueryBase.java:86)
    at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.query_dsl.Query.serialize(Query.java:1164)
    at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.query_dsl.BoolQuery.serializeInternal(BoolQuery.java:143)
    at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.query_dsl.QueryBase.serialize(QueryBase.java:86)
    at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.query_dsl.Query.serialize(Query.java:1164)
```

dependencies:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>co.elastic.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-java</artifactId>
            <version>7.17.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Why you are not using Java High Level client as you are using Elasticsearch 7.10 version. Elasticsearch have release new java client in ES 7.17 version and you might face issue with old version.

Answer (score 5):

It's failing to serialize JsonData fields in your search request. You have to use a `JacksonJsonpGenerator` for the `JacksonJsonpMapper`.

```
final StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
try (final JacksonJsonpGenerator generator = new JacksonJsonpGenerator(new JsonFactory().createGenerator(writer))) {
    searchRequest.serialize(generator, new JacksonJsonpMapper());
}
final String searchRequestString = writer.toString();
```